# Convert string to XXX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In [queel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel), I can do:

```
User.where{id.eq "2" | admin.eq true}
```

to query. I want to know if I can trans [sic] a string, which is a condition like:

```
string = "id: 2"
```

or

```
string = "id.eq '2' | admin.eq true"
```

and run:

```
User.where{string}
```

or

```
User.where(string)
```

The result is not a hash. How can I do that?

Comment: Use this link to improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: BTW, the XXX is called "a hash".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `hash` and not `string`. You can use it like this,

```
hash = {id: 2}
User.where(hash)
```

And if you really want to use `string` you can do it like this,

```
string = "id = 2"
User.where(string)
```

If you want to execute the string you can use `eval`. In that case it will be like this,

```
string = "{id: 2}"
User.where(eval string)
```

Comment: Yes, but the point is how to convert string to condition? (just kidding name). You know `User.where(id: 2)` is right syntax, If the string is `"id: 2"` , we could not change it, so how to let `User.where(string)` run. Is there a method like this: `User.where(string.to_xxx)` OR `User.where(xxx(string))`

Answer (score -1):

**NB** to use the variant below, one should read first five pages of Google output on query “ruby eval is evil.”

```
User.where(instance_eval("{#{string}}"))
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `JSON.parse` requires valid JSON, does not it?: `JSON.parse "{id: 2}" #⇒ JSON::ParserError: 784: unexpected token at '{id: 2}'`

Comment: I downvoted because of the instance_eval; I thought your warning was too weak.  This answer really needs an explicit statement such as, "Do not do this!  It will break your application's security"

Comment: @WayneConrad you might think whatever you want as well as to downvote each answer containing those perfectly valid, useful language constraints, that were introduced by Matz to make ruby as powerful as it is. I never belonged to the religious sect of Eval Haters; in some cases it is great.

Comment: On further reflection, I wish I had not downvoted.  I still think the answer would be better with a stronger warning, but a downvote was heavy-handed,  I apologize.

Comment: @WayneConrad there is absolutely nothing to apologize; SO is being made by humans for humans and fortunately all of us have different opinions (otherwise it would be too boring to live at all.) What matters, is that the answer still exists, and it has (at the moment) the score `-1`, which in turn means that: a) the described way of implementing this exists, and b) it is mainly not appreciated by the community. I personally appreciate any opinion sharing, despite whether it is positive or negative. Thanks for being not indifferent.